# Regular Expression for StartsWith and EndsWith?

Tags: regex

For example I want to find all strings that start with `"abc"` and end with `"xyz"` with 1 regex.

```
"abc...xyz"
"abcnfdgljfgdxxyz"
"abc3748 95347958347589xyz"
```

*I'm looking for a regular expression as a **string** and **not bound** to any specific language.*

Comment: Search for regex anchors.

Comment: Read the tutorial at www.regular-expressions.info. This is extremely basic, and should be covered there.

Comment: What is "a regular expression as string and not bound to any specific language"? Regular expressions depend always on the implementation in a specific language. Because of that the language tag is required for all regex questions, [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info).

Comment: Luckily this regular expression is so simple that it should be the same in almost all languages.

Answer (score 5):

This should be valid for you:

```
^abc.*xyz$
```

Comment: No need for the parentheses.